# Use decay animation in react native with loop animation

Tags: react-native, animation

I have been learning animations in react native lately and I am trying to implement some animations.
I thought of creating a bouning ball animation and I did. all is working fine but this animation is looping between the height and 0 and feels very unnatural. so I wanted to add a decay where on each bounce it will bounce less height(basically exponentially decreasing).

I tried to added decay animation at multiple places just to see what happens but wherever I put the Animated.decay code, the animation either froze or I got some errors.

this is my current code

```
FALL_HEIGHT = 200;
const translateY = useRef(new Animated.Value(-FALL_HEIGHT)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.spring(translateY, {
          toValue: 0,
          useNativeDriver: true,
          overshootClamping: true,
          bounciness: 20,
        }),
        Animated.spring(translateY, {
          toValue: -FALL_HEIGHT,
          useNativeDriver: true,
          bounciness: 1,
          overshootClamping: true,
        }),
      ])
    ).start(() => {});
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [animationValue, setAnimationValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

const startAnimation = () => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(animationValue, {
          toValue: 20,
          duration: 2000,
        }),
        Animated.timing(animationValue, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 2000,
        }),
      ]),
      {
        iterations: 10,
      }
    ).start();
  };

setAnimationValue(new Animated.Value(0)); // where it has to start again

startAnimation(); // to start the animation
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).